# How do I link (shallow copy) a global var to a local container variable/constant?

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

Note: This post has been revised numerous times.

**Problem:** I'm *trying* to link (shallow copy) a global var to a local var to broaden its scope.

I'm able to assign the *local* array 'photos' into the empty array 'photoInfos'.

Unfortunately that doesn't translate into a global 'photoInfos'.

The compiler is complaining that I need either an init() or a getter/setter method.

So after some studying I came up with *computed* ivars for the **Globals**:

```
import UIKit

var photoInfos = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()
var gPhotoInfos:Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {
    set {
        photoInfos = newValue
    }
    get {
       return photoInfos
    }
}
```

...

```
let myPhotos = responseDict["photos"] as? NSDictionary
let photos: AnyObject? = myPhotos!["photo"]

// ...assigning to a local empty var works:
var myPersonalPhotos:AnyObject?
myPersonalPhotos = photos
println(myPersonalPhotos)

gPhotoInfos = photos  // <--- compile error.
```

Unfortunately I got this:

```
...Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'Array<Dictionary<String, String>>'
```

**Question:** am I on the right track of porting a *local* var into its respective *global* iVar?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use computed properties (they're not called ivars in Swift) for this.

The issue is simply that the types are incompatible and Swift is type-safe.

You can declare `gPhotoInfos`:

```
var gPhotoInfos : Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
var gPhotoInfos : [[String : String]]
```

The assignment fails because you have declared `photos` to be an optional AnyObject (`AnyObject?`).

If `photos` is, in fact an array of string/string dictionaries, then you can unwrap the optional and downcast to the correct type. After that the assignment will work. For example:

```
if let unwrappedPhotos = photos {

    //unwrappedPhotos is now AnyObject instead of AnyObject?

    if let typedUnwrappedPhotos = unwrappedPhotos as? [[String : String]] {
        gPhotoInfos = typedUnwrappedPhotos
    } else {
        // photos is some other type, not [[String : String]]
    }

} else {

    // photos is nil

}
```

You can do this a bit shorter by combining the unwrapping and the downcasting:

```
if let unwrappedPhotos = photos? as? [[String : String]] {

    //unwrappedPhotos is now [[String : String]]

    gPhotoInfos = unwrappedPhotos

} else {

    // photos is either nil or not unwrappedPhotos

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
if let myPhotos = photos {
   photoInfos = myPhotos
} else {
   println("*** WARNING: no photos. ***")
   return
}
```

to this:

```
if (photos != nil)
{
    photoInfos = photos!
}

else
{
    println("*** WARNING: no photos. ***")
    return
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I got the following: ... '[String]' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

Comment: That formatting style is incredibly difficult to follow.